# Shopify Delivery Date Picker - turn off days

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, shopify

I added this code to my shopify site http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/cart-page/capture-delivery-date. It works great, but I can't figure out how to turn off some days. I don't deliver overnight or even 2 day, so I want to disable the ability for customers to choose days that are today's date + the following 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the min and max dates in your **delivery-date.liquid** snippet.

To set the minimum date to today's date + 7 days (instead of +1 day in the sample code provided):

```
jQuery("#date").datepicker( { 
  minDate: +7, 
  maxDate: "+2M"
} );
```

See the jQuery UI docs for more info on [`minDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) and [`maxDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate).

You can also [disable weekends](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-noWeekends):

```
jQuery("#date").datepicker( { 
  minDate: +7, 
  maxDate: "+2M",
  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
} );
```

...or [disable specific days](http://tokenposts.blogspot.ca/2011/05/jquery-datepicker-disable-specific.html).